# How to combine isset with is_array

Tags: php, isset

I am using `is_array` function but need to use `isset` as well, as if nothing is selected I am get a undefined index error.

I am still learning `PHP` so not sure how to combine what I have written with `isset`, my code is below

```
$special = $_POST['special'];
if (is_array($_POST['special'])) {
    $special = implode(",", $_POST['special']);
} else {
    $special = $_POST['special'];
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Where did you use isarray?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to assign the value of `$_POST['special']` to `$special` whether it is set or not. That is why you are getting an error. The following might work:

```
$special = ""; 
if (isset($_POST['special'])) {
    if(is_array($_POST['special'])) {
        $special = implode(",", $_POST['special']);
    } else {
        $special = $_POST['special'];
    }
}
```

If `$_POST['special']` is an array it will use implode to convert it to a string and assign it to `$special`.

If it is not an array, but is still set, then assign the value to `$special`

Comment: Yes, yes, I know, pre-optimization is the root of all evil etc. etc., but I just feel like using `isset` twice on the same variable is bad practise.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `is_array` , you can force everything to be array ...

```
$special = isset($_POST['special']) ? $_POST['special'] : null;
$special = implode(",", (array) $special);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a value of `$_POST` array whether it is set or not. And you tell the computer if `$_POST['special']` is set then assign it to `$special`, if it is not set assign it to `$special` again. Then you get that error.

Your if statement has not a mean.

```
$special = "";
$pos = false;
if (isset($_POST['special'])) 
{
    $pos = strpos($_POST['special'], ',');
    if($pos !== false)
    {
        $special = implode(",", $_POST['special']);
    }
    else
    {
        $special = $_POST['special'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first line will throw an error if no value `$_POST[ 'special' ]` exists, because assigning `$_POST[ 'special' ]` to `$special` is assuming that there is a value. The correct way to do what you are wanting is as follows:

```
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'special' ] ) )
    $special = implode( ',', $_POST[ 'special' ] );
else
    $special = null;
```

With the above code, you can later in your script check if `$special` is `null` using a strict comparison. If it is, then `$_POST[ 'special' ]` was not set. Otherwise, you can assume that it contains the imploded string value.

You can, of course, add more checks such as making sure the value is not empty as well, among other things.